# Pass environment variables to Spring Boot application with Maven

Tags: spring-boot, maven, environment-variables, yaml

I am using Spring Boot `3.2.1`.

I don't want to put sensitive data at config file as `application.yml`. So they are referring to environment variables.

Execution works fine at IntelliJ configuration settings for application (at `Environment variables` section).

However, it fails for maven execution from the console:

```
./mvnw -Ddemo-api-key=all56 -Ddemo-host=https://demo.api spring-boot:run
```

Here is exception details:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not enough variable values available to expand 'demo-host'
        at org.springframework.web.util.UriComponents$VarArgsTemplateVariables.getValue(UriComponents.java:367) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.util.UriComponents.expandUriComponent(UriComponents.java:262) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.util.HierarchicalUriComponents$PathSegmentComponent.expand(HierarchicalUriComponents.java:960) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.util.HierarchicalUriComponents.expandInternal(HierarchicalUriComponents.java:434) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.util.HierarchicalUriComponents.expandInternal(HierarchicalUriComponents.java:52) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.util.UriComponents.expand(UriComponents.java:172) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
```

Here is a snippet from `application.yml`:

```
car-parks-url: ${demo-host}/cap-ws/getCarParks?apiKey=${demo-api-key}
```

If I will put it higher at `application.yml` it works fine:

```
demo-api-key: all56
demo-host: https://demo.api
```

URL is formed correctly and all data are pulled fine.

***Could not understand what is missed for passing it as the environment variables with maven?***

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's not the same as:

```
java -jar -Ddemo-api-key=all56 -Ddemo-host=https://demo.api myApp.jar
```

Where you are passing env vars ***directly to your application***.

If you do:

```
./mvnw -Ddemo-api-key=all56 \
-Ddemo-host=https://demo.api spring-boot:run
```

You are passing the vars to ***maven task and not to the application***.

You could use:

```
 ./mvnw  spring-boot:run \
 -Dspring-boot.run.arguments="--demo-host=https://demo.api --demo-api-key=all56"
```

or

```
 ./mvnw  spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="\
 -Ddemo-host=https://demo.api -Ddemo-api-key=all56"
```

Those commands indicate that you what to pass those vars to Spring Boot application.

***Additional resource:***

- [Spring Boot: Different ways to pass application properties](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-boot/different-ways-to-pass-application-properties.html)